# Representations and dual group ring

Tags: representation-theory

If $G$ is a finite group and $K$ is a field, every map $\chi \colon G \to K$ (such as a character for example) can identified with the element $\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g) g$ of the group algebra $KG$. This makes use of two facts: that $KG$ is finite-dimensional over $K$ and that it has a canonical basis ($G$). It is heavily used in Cohn, ``Further Algebra'', Chapter 6.

Naturally, the maps $\chi$ form the $K$-vector space dual to $KG$ (while $KG \cong \bigoplus_{g \in G} K$ this space is $\prod_{g \in G} K$). My question is: what reference on representation theory keeps these things cleanly separate? In particular: which structure to define on the algebra (involutions: complex conjugation, inversion on G), which one on the dual (``hermitian'' inner products w.r.t. the two involutions), etc.).

I don't think there is a practical problem with the identification, I just have an aversion to freely identifying vector spaces with their duals because I think it obscures the view on natural constructions.

Comment: Another important distinction: $\prod_{g \in G} K$ contains ``constant $1$'' while $\bigoplus_{g \in G} K$ doesn't if $G$ is infinite. Hence $\prod_{g \in G} K$ is a unitary algebra while in general $KG$ is not.

Comment: The direct product is not studied very much directly when $G$ is infinite, instead some other structure on $G$ (such as a Haar measure, in the Lie group case) is used to cut out a convenient subspace (such as the L2 functions) and then that space is used. Once you do this, you also solve the dual space problem because now you can take continuous duals and recover the self-duality property.

Comment: @Joppy: But if it works for locally compact groups (not just compact ones) it should also work for infinite discrete groups (which are locally compact): the Haar measure is just counting measure.

Comment: Sure, and it does work: for instance you could take the group to be the integers, with the counting measure, and get square-summable sequences (sequence here meaning infinite in both directions) as the L2 space. But the dual L2 space is _itself_, the only subtle point is that the pairing between these spaces is linear in one variable and conjugate-linear in the other. This comes more-or-less directly from the definition of the inner product. So there is no real difference to keep track of.

Comment: @Joppy: I see, thank you! But then how do characters fit into the picture? They generally won't be integrable.

Comment: Characters (as they’re used in finite groups) are not as useful in infinite groups, and often something else is used instead. For example, for representations of Lie groups we often look at representations restricted to a maximal torus inside the group, giving “weight spaces”. As for an example of where characters are less useful, consider representations of the integers: these are precisely invertible matrices. All a character tells you is the trace of all powers of that matrix, but a lot more could be going on (think of upper triangular matrices with 1’s along the diagonal, for example).

Comment: Ok, but you are essentially saying not all modules will be semisimple. I am aware that other instances of representation theory will not just be like representation theory of finite groups with a few adjustments here and there. Still you might want to study simple modules (as a first step before studying cohomology). For example, for abelian groups it will lead you to Pontryagin duality.